# Routing table incorrect at startup

Tags: networking, routing

Whenever I reboot my Ubuntu server, the routing table is incorrect for the default route. The routing table correctly specifies the LAN IP address 192.168.124.0/24. All other traffic should go through the router at 192.168.124.253, but the default route specifies 192.168.124.254 for the gateway:

```
jos@hallway:~$ ip route list
default via 192.168.124.254 dev eth1  proto static
192.168.124.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.124.101
```

and similarly:

```
jos@hallway:~$ sudo route -n
[sudo] password for jos: 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.124.254 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.124.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

I have to manually correct this to .253, using:

```
sudo ip route del default
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.124.253
```

Otherwise, the server won't be able to reach the Internet.
Where does this .254 come from? It is not in my /etc/network/interfaces, or anywhere in /etc/iproute2. The server has a single ethernet interface with a static address. My /etc/network/interfaces is simply this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.124.101
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.124.253
  dns-nameservers 192.168.124.253 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

My /etc/resolv.conf:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.124.253
nameserver 192.168.124.253
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

So what is going on here?

Comment: please, can you post the output of **sudo route -n** after startup and /etc/resolv.conf content?

Comment: @Letizia I added the information to the question.

Comment: Try `grep -rH 192.168.124.254 /etc` and `grep -rH 192.168.124.254 /var`

Comment: @bain Yes! Thanks. There was a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` describing the network connection that contained the wrong router address. I must have created this years ago when I still ran X on it and used the network interface. I thought all network information was taken from /etc/network/interfaces, but it appears I was wrong.

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` is ignored if `managed=true` is set in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` ([NetworkManager docs](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager#doc))

Comment: @bain Thank you. I had indeed `managed=true` in NetworkManager.conf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetworkManager is still configuring the interface because `managed=true` is set in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

To disable NetworkManager and instead use `/etc/network/interfaces`, set `managed=false` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`